# Smote for oversampling multiclass dataset without undersampling majority class

Tags: r

This question is resolved see [Smote for oversampling multiclass dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47663024/solvedsmote-for-oversampling-multiclass-dataset)

---

While I have a small datset I want to oversample minority classes without undersampling majority class to fit better my model. my idea is to adapt smote to multiclass oversampling without undersmpling the majority class as presented with details below. The code works well but how can i add a condition to have all the classes equal to majority class after oversampling?
my current result is as below:  setosa versicolor  virginica 
        48         25         44 
This is my code

```
#NewSMOTE algorithm to balance a multiclass dataset without undersampling majority class(iris as example)
#get an unbalanced iris dataset 
set.seed(9850)
gp <-runif(nrow(iris))
iris<-iris[order(gp),]
s<-sample(150,71)
data<-iris[s,]
#sort classes in decreasing order
tab<-sort(table(data$Species),decreasing=TRUE) 
#majoritycases extrction
selMaj <- which(data$Species==names(tab[1]))
#takes data with minority classes in order to oversample it
data1<-data[data$Species!=names(tab[1]),]
#versicolor and viriginica are minority classes
Species <-factor(data1$Species)
dataminExs<-data.frame()
newExs1 <-data.frame()
class <- unique(Species)
for(i in 1:length(class)){
  # the column where the target variable is
  tgt <- which(names(data1) == "Species")
  #getting the minority class[i]
  minCl <- as.character(class[i])
   # get the cases of the minority class
  minExs <- which(data1[,tgt] == minCl)
  #concatenate all minority classes instances
   dataminExs<- rbind(dataminExs, data1[minExs,])
  print(nrow(dataminExs))
   #calculate percentage of oversampling
 perc.over= as.integer(length(selMaj)/length(minExs))*100
  # generate synthetic cases from these minExs
  newExs <- smote.exs(data1[minExs,],ncol(data1),perc.over,5)
    #all synthetic minority examples created
    newExs1<-rbind(newExs1, newExs)
  print(newExs1 )
alldatamin <-rbind(newExs1, dataminExs)
print(nrow(alldatamin))
     }
# the final data set (the undersample+the rare cases+the smoted exs)
newdataset <- rbind(data[selMaj,],alldatamin)

#function to oversample minority class
smote.exs <- function(data,tgt,N,k)
  # INPUTS:
  # data are the rare cases (the minority "class" cases)
  # tgt is the name of the target variable
  # N is the percentage of over-sampling to carry out;
  # and k is the number of nearest neighours to use for the generation
  # OUTPUTS:
  # The result of the function is a (N/100)*T set of generated
  # examples with rare values on the target
{
  nomatr <- c()
  T <- matrix(nrow=dim(data)[1],ncol=dim(data)[2]-1)
  for(col in seq.int(dim(T)[2]))
    if (class(data[,col]) %in% c('factor','character')) {
      T[,col] <- as.integer(data[,col])
      nomatr <- c(nomatr,col)
    } else T[,col] <- data[,col]

  if (N < 100) { # only a percentage of the T cases will be SMOTEd
    nT <- NROW(T)
    idx <- sample(1:nT,as.integer((N/100)*nT))
    T <- T[idx,]
    N <- 100
  }

  p <- dim(T)[2]
  nT <- dim(T)[1]

  ranges <- apply(T,2,max)-apply(T,2,min)

  nexs <-  as.integer(N/100) # this is the number of artificial exs generated
  # for each member of T
  new <- matrix(nrow=nexs*nT,ncol=p)    # the new cases

  for(i in 1:nT) {

    # the k NNs of case T[i,]
    xd <- scale(T,T[i,],ranges)
    for(a in nomatr) xd[,a] <- xd[,a]==0
    dd <- drop(xd^2 %*% rep(1, ncol(xd)))
    kNNs <- order(dd)[2:(k+1)]

    for(n in 1:nexs) {
      # select randomly one of the k NNs
      neig <- sample(1:k,1)

      ex <- vector(length=ncol(T))

      # the attribute values of the generated case
      difs <- T[kNNs[neig],]-T[i,]
      new[(i-1)*nexs+n,] <- T[i,]+runif(1)*difs
      for(a in nomatr)
        new[(i-1)*nexs+n,a] <- c(T[kNNs[neig],a],T[i,a])[1+round(runif(1),0)]

    }
  }
  newCases <- data.frame(new)
  for(a in nomatr)
    newCases[,a] <- factor(newCases[,a],levels=1:nlevels(data[,a]),labels=levels(data[,a]))

  newCases[,tgt] <- factor(rep(data[1,tgt],nrow(newCases)),levels=levels(data[,tgt]))
  colnames(newCases) <- colnames(data)
  newCases
}
```

Comment: The package `DMwR` has an implementation of SMOTE.  Is there a reason that you don't want to use that?

Comment: yes because i am going to implement a new balanced solution called SCUT which is applicable for a multiclass dataset and following the SCUT algorithm i have to split the original dataset imbalanced with n classes into n datasets each one has only a class label So to oversample using smote i have to change smote code for one level class label

Comment: I couldn't get the synthetics minority classes examples in this data.frame newExs1<-NULL
  newExs1<- rbind(newExs1,newExs)

Comment: Was there an error message?

Comment: No error appears and even when i print out the result of the loop for it works. Normally in the newExs1 i will find the new examples generated for both minority classes But i find just of one minority class  #indices of all synthetic minority examples created
  newExs1<-NULL
  newExs1<- rbind(newExs1,newExs)

Comment: i gotta it i define newExs1<-NULL as an empty dataframe before the loop for

Comment: i retest again and i print out the resuts and i figure out that the function 
  newExs <- smote.exs(data1[minExs,],ncol(data1),perc.over,5) didn't oversample the minority classes!!!